# Error Cannot convert lambda expression in subscribe for an IObservable<Point>

Tags: wpf, lambda, system.reactive

i am trying to implement a standard drag and drop image in wpf using Rx.

```
var mouseDown = from evt in Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseButtonEventArgs>(image, "MouseLeftButtonDown")
                          select evt.EventArgs.GetPosition(image);

            var mouseUp = Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseButtonEventArgs>(this, "MouseLeftButtonUp");

            var mouseMove = from evt in Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventArgs>(this, "MouseMove")
                            select evt.EventArgs.GetPosition(this);

            var q = from startLocation in mouseDown
                    from endLocation in mouseMove.TakeUntil(mouseUp)
                    select new Point 
                    {
                        X = endLocation.X - startLocation.X,
                        Y = endLocation.Y - startLocation.Y
                    };

            q.ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current).Subscribe(point =>
            {
                Canvas.SetLeft(image, point.X);
                Canvas.SetTop(image, point.Y);
            });
```

i get the error Error `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.IObserver<System.Windows.Point>' because it is not a delegate type`

what am i missing ?

Comment: Your code works ok for me.  Have you referenced Rx-Main and Rx-WPF?

Comment: Please check if your target platform says .NET 4 Client Profile and if so then change it to .NET 4.

Comment: i changed the target platform ...it still does not build

Comment: do you have `System` imported?  The `Subscribe` you are using is an extension method defined by a class in that namespace.

Comment: can you please post this as answer, with some more details , so that i can accept it ...

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The namespace `System.Reactive.Linq` contains the static class `Observable` which defines all the extension methods for common reactive combinators. It resides in `System.Reactive.dll`

The extension methods for `IObservable<T>.Subscribe` such as `Subscribe(onNext)`, `Subscribe(onNext, onError)` are however defined in `mscorlib` in the static class `System.ObservableExtensions`.

tl;dr:

- For Rx/Observable extension methods you need to import `System.Reactive.Linq` = `using System.Reactive.Linq;`
- For Subscribe overloads you need to import `System` = `using System;`

Answer (score 24):

To make this a clearer answer based on @Gideon Engelberths comment 5th down in the question I was missing the 'using System;' using directive in my class:

```
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System;
```

Which then fixed up the compiler issue. Thanks Gideon.

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled across this question and wanted to add, that I had to add more References to the Project.
 The Reference to `System.Reactive.Linq` alone was not sufficient in my case.

After adding those three the compiler issue was solved:

- `System.Reactive.Core`
- `System.Reactive.Interfaces`
- `System.Reactive.Linq`

Thanks to @Gideon Engelberths comment and The Senator's answer.